# (Android) Change language doesn't work properly

Tags: java, android, android-studio, locale

I'm choosing the language of my app in the `MainActivity.java` and sometimes it doesn't work properly.

This is my code on the `onCreate`method:

```
if(!SaveSharedPreference.getUserId(MainActivity.this).equals("")) {
    if (SaveSharedPreference.getWhoLoggedIn(MainActivity.this).equals("Main_User")) {
        FetchUserLanguage fetchUserLanguage = new FetchUserLanguage();
        fetchUserLanguage.execute();
    } 
} else {
    sDefSystemDefaultLanguage = Resources.getSystem().getConfiguration().locale;
    Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
    configuration.locale = sDefSystemDefaultLanguage;
    getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(configuration, getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
}
```

In the `FetchUserLanguage` I'm getting the language for each user from my database (it is returning the value correctly).

The method where I set the `Locale` is the next:

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    switch (result) {
        case "English":
            locale = new Locale("en");
            configuration = new Configuration();
            configuration.locale = locale;
            getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(configuration,
                    getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
            break;
        case "Deutsch":
            locale = new Locale("de");
            configuration = new Configuration();
            configuration.locale = locale;
            getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(configuration,
                    getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
            break;
        default:
            locale = Resources.getSystem().getConfiguration().locale;
            configuration = new Configuration();
            configuration.locale = locale;
            getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(configuration,
                    getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
            break;
    }
}
```

When I run the app from the Android Studio it works perfect and all the app is set in the selected language, but then, if I close and open it again, the first screen is being shown in English, (the other are in German). The language of the device is English so do the default language of the Android project.

Maybe I'm missing something.

Thank you very much.

Comment: when the user swich the language save it. When the Splash screen is shown(or after a relaunch) set the saved language for the app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I´ve found the solution.

The problem was that I was doing the translation process in an asynchronous thread, so the app was still running and some of the layouts weren't changed to the new language before the screen changed.

The solution is to create the Intent at the end of the `onPostExecute()` method:

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    switch (result) {
        case "English":
            locale = new Locale("en");
            Locale.setDefault(locale);
            configuration = new Configuration();
            configuration.locale = locale;
            SaveSharedPreference.setUserLanguage(MainActivity.this, locale.getLanguage());
            getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(configuration,
                    getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
            break;
        case "Deutsch":
            locale = new Locale("de");
            Locale.setDefault(locale);
            configuration = new Configuration();
            configuration.locale = locale;
            SaveSharedPreference.setUserLanguage(MainActivity.this, locale.getLanguage());
            getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(configuration,
                    getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
            break;
        default:
            locale = Resources.getSystem().getConfiguration().locale;
            Locale.setDefault(locale);
            SaveSharedPreference.setUserLanguage(MainActivity.this, locale.getLanguage());
            configuration = new Configuration();
            configuration.locale = locale;
            getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(configuration,
                    getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
            break;
    }
    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainMenuActivity.class);
    if(SaveSharedPreference.getUserType(MainActivity.this).equals("Full")) {
        intent.putExtra("Type", "Full");
    }
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();
}
```